# OpenAM : Can't login with custom authentication module

Tags: openam

I developed a custom authentication module by following the [example](https://github.com/ForgeRock/openam-auth-sample) and installed into top level realm. OpenAM 11.0.0.

[image]

Then I open the test page for my auth module.
[image]

The login fails with the error "**Login/password combination is invalid.**"

However, if I open `/openam` after seeing this error message, it says I am logged-in.

[image]

Here is the `process` code of the `AMLoginModule`

```
public int process(Callback[] callbacks, int state) throws LoginException
{

    if (debug.messageEnabled())
    {
        debug.message("Authentication module process() is called. state: " + state);
    }


    switch (state)
    {

        case STATE_BEGIN:
        // No time wasted here - simply modify the UI and
        // proceed to next state
        substituteUIStrings();
        return STATE_AUTH;

        case STATE_AUTH:
        return ISAuthConstants.LOGIN_SUCCEED;

        case STATE_ERROR:
        return STATE_ERROR;
        default:
        throw new AuthLoginException("invalid state");

    }

}
```

You can see any username / password is accepted. The debug log shows that the module is called correctly.

```
[root@a3652f4b6f0f debug]# tail /openam/openam/debug/em 
em:06/15/2015 06:58:20:462 AM UTC: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
Authentication module process() is called. state: 1
em:06/15/2015 06:58:20:540 AM UTC: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
Authentication module process() is called. state: 2
em:06/15/2015 06:58:27:501 AM UTC: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
Authentication module init() is called
em:06/15/2015 06:58:27:507 AM UTC: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
Authentication module process() is called. state: 1
em:06/15/2015 06:58:27:625 AM UTC: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
Authentication module process() is called. state: 2
```

Please why do I see the error "**Login/password combination is invalid.**" in test login page?

Comment: The callback definitions and service schema would be good to see

Comment: Hi, the post is updated

Comment: XUI does a REST call to the identity endpoint in the end (see developer tools output) ... not nice  .. I know.
the console output suggests that OpenAM can not retrieve a user profile from the configured data stores and this seems to be the issue.

You may first try with legacy UI

Comment: Yes, it is the XUI returns such error `{"code":400,"reason":"Bad Request","message":"Identity demo of type user not found."}`.  Could you please answer the question in regular way so that I can mark it as an answer ?

Comment: did you solve this problem? could you share it? I have faced same error

Comment: I gave up OpenAM because its free version is full of bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have user profile to login. You need to have the username in your datastore which you pass to `SampleAuthPrincipal("username")` constructor .

```
@Override
public Principal getPrincipal() {
    return new SampleAuthPrincipal("username");
}
```

This should resolve your problem.